# Directx 11 runtime error

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2013, directx

I am trying to run Frank D Luna's demo project on visual studio 2013(Express) and I am getting an `unexpected error encountered error code: D3D11_FILE_NOT_FOUND` - do you want to debug the application etc, when calling `D3D11Compilefromfile`

Here is where a break point has triggered:

```
HR(D3DX11CreateEffectFromMemory(compiledShader->GetBufferPointer(), compiledShader->GetBufferSize(), 0, md3dDevice, &mFX));
```

Comment: Changed your title to runtime error as it's not a compilation error; apart from that: you talk about errors for D3D11Compilefromfile but the code line shown is about D3DX11CreateEffectFromMemory?

Comment: thank you for chaning the title :)  yes that is where iam getting a break point

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure you are using the latest Effects 11 which is on [CodePlex](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=271568).

Secondly, the code you posted is not calling `D3D11CompileFromFile` so it's difficult to say what's the issue here. `D3D11_FILE_NOT_FOUND` is usually because the current working directory isn't what you think it is, or the path you provided is incorrect. BTW, the latest Effects11 has a `D3DX11CreateEffectFromFile` so you don't have to code this two-step process yourself.

Thirdly, since you are using VS 2013 Express, be sure to read [Where is the DirectX SDK (2013 Edition)?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/07/01/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2013-edition.aspx) and [Visual Studio 2013 and Windows 8.1 SDK RTM are now available](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/10/18/visual-studio-2013-and-windows-8-1-sdk-rtm-are-now-available.aspx). Hopefully you are just avoiding using the legacy DirectX SDK and D3DX all together (see [Living without D3DX](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/08/21/living-without-d3dx.aspx)), but if not be sure you have the right include/lib path order as indicated on MSDN.

Comment: thak you my friend ;)